# How to edit article in mongoose and nodejs

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to create a blog with nodejs. I can upload file and data in to mongoose sucessful. My problem is: I can't edit the data.

```
router.post('/admin/create-article',upload.any(), function(req,res,next){
    if(req.files){
        req.files.forEach(function(file){
            var filename = (new Date).valueOf() + "-" + file.originalname;
            fs.rename(file.path, 'public/uploads/images/thumbnails/' + filename, function(err){
                if(err)throw err;

                        //save to mongoose
                        var newArticle = {
                            title:req.body.title,
                            featured_image:filename,
                            article_content:req.body.article_content,
                            created_at:moment().format('MMMM Do YYY, h:mm:ss a')
                        };

                        Article.create(newArticle,function(err,result){
                            if(err){
                            }
                            res.json(result);
                        });

                    });
        });

    }
});
```

And this is for editing (not working):

```
router.put('/admin/article/:id/edit',upload.any(), function(req,res,next){                                                                                                                       
            if(req.files){
                    req.files.forEach(function(file){
                        var filename = (new Date).valueOf() + "-" + file.originalname;

                        fs.readFile(file.path, 'public/uploads/images/thumbnails/' + filename, function(err){
                    //      if(err)throw err;

                                    //save to mongoose
                                    var editArticle = {
                                        title:req.body.title,
                                        featured_image:filename,
                                        article_content:req.body.article_content,
                                        created_at:moment().format('MMMM Do YYY, h:mm:ss a'),
                                    };

                                    Article.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, editArticle, function(err,article){
                                        if(err){
                                            rep.flash('error', err.message);
                                            return res.redirect('/article/' + req.params.id);
                                        }
                                        req.flash('success','Articles updated successfully');
                                        console.log('success');
                                        res.redirect('/admin/articles/');
                                    });

                                });


                    });

            }

});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you post the exact error?

Comment: I can not update the content into the mongodb. Could you please tell me know what i was wrong at the editing code part?

Comment: Can you be more clear? What error do you have? Or just not error? Did you tried to debug the code?

Answer (score 1):

If you use [`findByIdAndUpdate`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findByIdAndUpdate) mongoose command you should use the `$set` operator.

```
...
//save to mongoose
var editArticle = {
  title          : req.body.title,
  featured_image : filename,
  article_content: req.body.article_content,
  created_at     : moment().format('MMMM Do YYY, h:mm:ss a'),
};

Article.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: editArticle}, ...);
```

Comment: Thank you. But its not working. it's wrong at feature_image:filename. But i do not know how to fix it.